# Defining a controller at the app module

Tags: angularjs

I have an app module, want to register a controller for app module.
Is it ok to define a controller for the app module?

Regards,
ng-R

Answer (score 1):

You can organize your components in modules the way you want. For a very small app, you can imagine using a single app module containing all the components. For larger applications, splitting components in technical and/or functional modules is a good idea.

In the end, at runtime, what matters is that the needed controller is part of the app module or of any of the modules it depends on, transitively.